# Generating Multiple Columns Based On The Column Content

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I am in need of generating a result which joins two user related tables - Users and Usermeta. These are from a Wordpress MySQL DB.

User Table -

```
ID user_email
1  abc@gmail.com
2  xyz@gmail.com
3  1sf@email.com
```

Usermeta Table -

```
Umeta_ID user_id meta_key          meta_value
1000     1       billing_phone     9876443100
1001     1       billing_postcode  670001
1002     1       billing_address   Somewhere here, Delhi
1003     2       billing_phone     9876345188
1004     2       billing_postcode  650021
1005     2       billing_address   7th Lane, Bangalore
1003     3       billing_phone     7852562100
1004     3       billing_postcode  400521
1005     3       billing_address   Fancy Area, Mumbai
```

As you can the user_id column in Usermeta table refers the **ID** column from the User table.

I am in dire need of a MYSQL query which gives out the result in this manner -

```
ID user_email     billing_phone billing_postcode billing_address
1  abc@gmail.com  9876443100    670001           Somewhere here, Delhi
2  abc@gmail.com  9876345188    650021           7th Lane, Bangalore
3  1sf@gmail.com  7852562100    400521           Fancy Area, Mumbai
```

I tried doing an UNION on two joins like this

```
SELECT 6ft_users.ID, 6ft_usermeta.meta_value as PHONE_NUMBER
FROM 6ft_users
INNER JOIN 6ft_usermeta
ON 6ft_users.ID=6ft_usermeta.user_id
WHERE 6ft_usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'billing_phone'
UNION
SELECT 6ft_users.ID, 6ft_usermeta.meta_value as POSTCODE
FROM 6ft_users
INNER JOIN 6ft_usermeta
ON 6ft_users.ID=6ft_usermeta.user_id
WHERE 6ft_usermeta.meta_key LIKE 'billing_postcode';
```

But this is not helping as I get only one column - PHONE_NUMBER. I tried a few other things but to no avail. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT U.ID, 
       U.user_email, 
       MAX(IF(UM.meta_key = 'billing_phone', UM.meta_value, '')) AS billing_phone, 
       MAX(IF(UM.meta_key = 'billing_postcode', UM.meta_value, '')) AS billing_postcode, 
       MAX(IF(UM.meta_key = 'billing_address', UM.meta_value, '')) AS billing_address
FROM 6ft_users U
LEFT JOIN 6ft_usermeta UM ON U.ID = UM.user_id
GROUP BY U.ID
```